# how to invert the following function?

Tags: inverse

I am trying to invert the function below with respect to $w$ but in vain. Can you show me how ?

$$m[w,x] = sgn[x]|x|^w$$

where $w\geq 0, x \in [-1,1]$, which results in $m[w,x] \in [-1,1]$

I am not sure if below is the correct answer ?
$$w = sgn(x) \frac{log(m)}{log(|x|)}$$

Comment: Consider cases for $\operatorname{sgn} x$.

Comment: $$\frac{\log(|m|)}{\log(|x|)}$$